# OSGi Declarative Services in Eclipse, multiple service interfaces, and Thread Safety

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-rcp, equinox, declarative-services

I just stumbled over a phenomenon in my code which comes down to this:

I have an OSGi Declarative Service providing two service interfaces configured as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" activate="init" deactivate="dispose" enabled="true" name="redacted.redactedstore">
   <implementation class="redacted.RedactedStore"/>
   <service>
      <provide interface="redacted.IRedactedStore"/>
      <provide interface="redacted.IRedactedStoreControl"/>
   </service>
</scr:component>
```

In my code, I have two different threads which both open a `ServiceTracker` to get the service instance, but via different interfaces:

```
tracker = new ServiceTracker<>(getBundle().getBundleContext(), <serviceClass>.class, null);
tracker.open();
tracker.waitForService(1000l);
```

So one thread uses `IRedactedStore` as service class and the other uses `IRedactedStoreControl` as service interface.

So what seems to happen is that when both threads run in parallel at the right time, the Equinox SCR will instantiate not one (as I would expect) but two instances of the component implementation class.

Is this behavior correct? Or is this a bug in the Equinox implementation of OSGi?

If the behavior is correct, can I do something in my code to prevent that by configuring the service another way? (of course I could restructure the service so it only provides one interface, or I could synchronize the service trackers...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For non prototype scope component I would expect that it is created only once.
See [declarative services spec](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html#service.component-service.element).

If this issue only happens when the service trackers run in parallel then I suspect it might be an concurrency issue in equinox scr.

Comment: Correct, It should be one service object registered under two service names.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to reproduce it with a minimal example and file a bug.